# Share global pinia store between components

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have two vue components with own loaders, mounted into two already rendered DOM nodes:

Component A:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import ComponentA from '@/Vue/ComponentA.vue';
import {createPinia} from 'pinia';

createApp(ComponentA).use(createPinia()).mount(document.querySelector('.c-component-a'));
```

Component B:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import ComponentB from '@/Vue/ComponentB.vue';
import {createPinia} from 'pinia';

createApp(ComponentA).use(createPinia()).mount(document.querySelector('.c-component-b'));
```

Now, I want to load a global pinia store into multiple components:

Pinia store:

```
import {defineStore} from 'pinia';

export type RootState = {
    foobar: number;
}

export const useGlobalApplicationStore = defineStore({
    id: 'global',
    state: () => ({
        foobar: 100
    } as RootState),
    actions: {
        setFoobar(payload: number): void {
            this.foobar = payload;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getFoobar(state: RootState): number {
            return state.foobar;
        }
    }
})
```

If component A sets a value in this store, component B should react to changes.

Component A:

```
const globalApplicationStore = useGlobalApplicationStore();
setTimeout(() => {
   globalApplicationStore.setFoobar(400);
}, 2000);
```

Output of {{globalApplicationStore.foobar}} in component A changes from 100 to 400 after 2 seconds, as expected.

Component B:

```
const globalApplicationStore = useGlobalApplicationStore();
```

Output of {{globalApplicationStore.foobar}} in component B does not change from 100 to 400.
I guess, both components loads the store as local instances.

How can I share a store between seperate mounted components?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a long search I found out that it's pretty easy (as often...).
In my case, I use the progressive aspect of Vue.js to put apps in different places of my HTML code. Specifically, I want to populate a shopping cart icon in the header of my layout with the number of items. So I am using a App.vue for my product-app and a Basket.vue for my basket-indicator.

The simple trick is to instantiate pinia just once. Let's say you have a main.js as an entry-point of your app:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Basket from "./Basket.vue";

import {createPinia} from 'pinia';

const pinia = createPinia();

// Init App
createApp(App)
   .use(pinia)  
   .mount("#app");

// Init Basket
createApp(Basket)
    .use(pinia)   
    .mount("#basket");
```

In your App.vue you just import your stores (in my case a product store and a cart store).

```
<script setup>
... import components ...

import {useProductStore} from "@/stores/ProductStore";
import {useCartStore} from "@/stores/CartStore";

const productStore = useProductStore();
const cartStore = useCartStore();

productStore.fill();

</script>

<template>
... your components ...
</template>
```

the same in your Basket.vue:

```
<script setup>
import CartWidget from "@/components/CartWidget.vue";

import {useCartStore} from "@/stores/CartStore";
import {useProductStore} from "@/stores/ProductStore";

const cartStore = useCartStore();
const productStore = useProductStore();

productStore.fill();

</script>

<template>
    <div class="container">
        <CartWidget/>
    </div>
</template>
```

That's it.

"pinia": "^2.0.17",
"vue": "^3.2.39"

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thanks a lot. In the meantime I created my solution by using localStorage with listeners, but in the next project I will use it this way.